# Move-Item not moving all files

Tags: powershell

I have a flash drive with about 500 mp3 files (give or take).
I am trying to divide the files into 99 random file groups and move each group into 6 sub-directories (its because of my car's player limitation)

I wanted to be efficient and use my PowerShell to quickly do so:

```
Get-ChildItem -File | Get-Random -Count 99 | % {Move-Item $_.fullname Dir_1}
```

Oddly enough I keep finding out the result ends up with between 75 or 97 files moved instead an exact 99.

Initially I assumed the `Get-Random` was returning a few files more than once so I checked with:

```
(Get-ChildItem -File | Get-Random -Count 99 | Sort-Object -Unique fullname).Count
```

but the output I kept getting was 99.

I switched the flash drive to a second one - same result.
Manually moving files works as expected.
Similar results were displayed when using different numbers (randomly selecting 11 files - 8 moved).

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have an error in your first example with `-Count 11`? Are you suppressing errors anywhere that might hide the fact that some of your `Move-Item` calls are failing?

Comment: my first example was supposed to be 99 (fixed it now). I have similar results when choosing different numbers as well (added that in as well)
no errors received and none are suppressed.

Comment: Any files with `[` or `]` in name? `Get-ChildItem -File | Get-Random -Count 99 | Move-Item -Destination Dir_1`

Comment: yes- there are some files with [ or ] in their name. why would they cause issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `Move-Item $_.FullName` with a positional parameter, you're using the `-Path` parameter. This parameter uses a form of shell globbing, so certain characters in path names are interpreted differently, such as `[` and `]`, which as you indicate in the comments are present in your file names.

You can avoid this by using the `-LiteralPath` parameter instead.

```
Get-ChildItem -File | Get-Random -Count 99 | % {Move-Item -LiteralPath $_.fullname -Destination Dir_1}
```

(It's a good idea to be explicit with parameters anyway.)

But even better than this is to take advantage of the pipeline. The `-LiteralPath` parameter can be bound by property name from an incoming pipeline object, and it has an alias of `-PSPath`, which happens to also be a property on the fileinfo objects from `Get-ChildItem`. This simplifies your command anyway:

```
Get-ChildItem -File | Get-Random -Count 99 | Move-Item -Destination Dir_1
```